# Помогите разместить блоки рядом

Tags: css

Внутри контейнера у меня чекбокс, значения бокс - нейм которого выводятся в цикле и 2 контейнера должны рядом выводить списки, но не получается разместить их рядом. Имею:

```css
.outerCheckbox {
  background: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.innerBox {
  width: 49%;
  background: coral;
}

.innerNamebox {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  background: darkgreen;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div className="outerCheckbox">
                <form>
                    <br/>
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerBox">
                            <input
                                onChange={() => changeHandler(item.id)}
                                type="checkbox"
                                id={item.id}
                                checked={item.checked}
                            /></div>))}
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerNamebox"><label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.name}</label></div>))}
                    <br />
                </form>
            </div>
```

Второй вариант вывода цикла:

[image: Второй вариант вывода цикла]

Получил в ответе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дерево после ответа:

```html
<div className="outerCheckbox">
                <form className="a">
                <div className='v'>
                    <br/>
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerBox">
                            <input
                                onChange={() => changeHandler(item.id)}
                                type="checkbox"
                                id={item.id}
                                checked={item.checked}
                            /></div>))}
                            <div className='asdass'>
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerNamebox"><label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.name}</label></div>))}
                        </div>
                    <br />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
```

Comment: а можно поточнее, что именно у вас и что хотелось бы видеть - вам хочется, чтобы рядом с checkbox стояли надписи мегафон и т.д.?

Comment: @Zhihar да, чтобы коробка была слева, а имя справа.

Comment: а обернуть в единый `div` вас почему не устраивает?

Comment: @Zhihar Оно уже в едином диве outerCheckbox, но как я и написал, вывод происходит в цикле и мне нужны четко фиксированные контейнеры слева и справа.

Comment: Додайте html розметку

Comment: @ZhyvkoRoman добавил.

Comment: @MrYogurt Добавь для тега <form> в стилях display:flex;

Comment: @ZhyvkoRoman не помогло, все растянулось по горизонтали.

Comment: @ZhyvkoRoman я добавил еще второй вариант вывода цикла, когда в 1 выражении выводятся бокс и имя, но оно все равно встает криво, может как то такой вариант можно выровнять? Вложенность такая: outerCheckbox > innerBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
  <div className="outerCheckbox">
                <form className="a">
                <div className='v'>
                    <br/>
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerBox">
                            <input
                                onChange={() => changeHandler(item.id)}
                                type="checkbox"
                                id={item.id}
                                checked={item.checked}
                            /></div>))}
                            </div>
                            <div className='asdass'>
                    {opNames.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.id} className="innerNamebox"><label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.name}</label></div>))}
                        </div>
                    <br />
                </form>

            </div>
```

Не знаю правильно ли я понял, да и реакт код тут.

```css
.outerCheckbox {
  background: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.a{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.innerBox {
  background: coral;
}

.innerNamebox {
  line-height: 21px;
  background: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
 <div class="outerCheckbox">
                <form class='a'>
                  <div class='v'>
                        <div class="innerBox"><input /></div>
                        <div class="innerBox"><input /></div>
                        <div class="innerBox"><input /></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='asdass'>
                        <div class="innerNamebox"><label>МТС</label></div>
                        <div class="innerNamebox"><label>МТС2</label></div>
                        <div class="innerNamebox"><label>МТС3</label></div>
                      </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Снова не помогло, добавил результат.

Comment: @MrYogurt надо обернуть innerBox и innerNamebox в div что бы сроботал flex. Нужна структура <from> в ней 2 блока div, а в них все что угодно уже. Должно роботать так как на примере

Comment: Прикрепил и дерево, все сделал как в ответе написано.

Comment: @MrYogurt div не там закрит, добавил код

Comment: Благодарю, все работает.